# How can I sort a string using C++ library function or STL?

Tags: c++

```
char word[100],p[100],result[4][100];
```

I want to sort the result[4][100] alphabetically. for example

```
result[0]="adbs";
result[1]="aacs";
result[2]="abef";
result[3]="abbm";
```

after sort it will be:

```
result[0]="aacs";
result[1]="abbm";
result[2]="abbm";
result[3]="adbs";
```

how can I do this using library function or STL. thanks in advance,

Answer (score 5):

What about making `result` an array of `std::string` instead and sorting that:

```
std::string result[4];

std::sort(result, result + (sizeof(result) / sizeof(result[0])));
```

Comment: Or, if you can use modern idioms, `std::sort(std::begin(result), std::end(result))`

Comment: Which header file do I need? "sort is not a member of std" warning is shown

Comment: @AbdusSattar-KUET: Your profile states you've written a C++ programming book but you've never heard of `<algorithm>` or `std::sort`?

Answer (score 1):

Mark B's answer is the C++ way to do things.

If you are stuck with the raw character arrays, you might be better off with a C-style approach.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

typedef int (*Comparator)(const void *, const void *);

int main() {
  const std::size_t cWords = 4;
  char result[cWords][100] = { "az", "ax", "aa", "ab" };
  std::qsort(result, cWords, sizeof(result[0]),
             reinterpret_cast<Comparator>(std::strcmp));
  for (std::size_t i = 0; i < cWords; ++i) {
    std::cout << result[i] << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The approach is essentially the same, but the details differ.

qsort takes void pointers, the type size, and a comparison function (that also uses void pointers) to implement a sort on any kind of data type.

std::sort uses templates to handle the type-specific details, so you can work at a higher level of abstraction and also get better type-safety.  But this can be harder to get right when you don't have a real type but just a fixed-length character array.  The std::sort approach can *potentially* be faster, since the compiler has the chance to inline the comparison function.